# Db:seed and passing variables for one to many relationship laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to seed a database, I have two questions

1) When there is a one to many relationship, I want to pass a parameter of another class (a previous table) in the new class of seeding. How can i achieve that?

2)`$row1->table2()->attach($row2->id);` What I achieve with that is to attach all the id of the table2 to table 1, right?

EDIT:

```
class LanguageTableSeeder extends Seeder {

public function run() {

    $lingua_it_catFintapelle= Linguacat::create(array(
        'nome'         => 'Finta pelle',
        'descrizione'  => 'Finta pelle nautica/Finta pelle tempo libero/Finta pelle aviazione/Finta pelle automoto/finta pelle contract/finta pelle uffici/finta pelle esterni',
        'lingua'       => 'it-IT',
        'id_cat'       => $catFintaPelle->id            
    ));
```

I have this code, the problem is that the id_cat field comes from another table, of another class that i already seeded, seeding all in the database seeder class allowed me to reuse the variables like this:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Eloquent::unguard();


        $this->call('Seeder');
        $this->command->info('Seed complete.'); 
    }

}


class CatTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {

        $catFintaPelle = Cat::create(array(
            'path_img'         => '/img/Materiale Imbottitura'

        ));
}
}

class LanguageTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {

        $lingua_it_catFintapelle= Linguacat::create(array(
            'nome'         => 'Finta pelle',
            'descrizione'  => 'Finta pelle nautica/Finta pelle tempo libero/Finta pelle aviazione/Finta pelle automoto/finta pelle contract/finta pelle uffici/finta pelle esterni',
            'lingua'       => 'it-IT',
            'id_cat'       => $catFintaPelle->id            
        ));
}
}
```

You see here, the i could reuse the id variables of the Seeding in the new Seed, saving me time.
But i read somewhere that each seed of each table should have hos own class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are seeding, it's assumed that you're seeding to a fresh database, so you could just hard code the values in rather than loading them from another table.

If you want to attach all of the ids though, you coudl do something like this:

```
$ids = OtherTable::all()->lists('id'); // this will generate an array of ids

$row1->table2()->sync($ids); // sync the ids with the relation
```

Comment: could you be more clear on how to sync id with second comman, i look at documentation and says it's used just for many to many relationship

Comment: Sorry, thought you were doing a many to many. Since you are seeding data, just hard code it, like this `$row1->table2()->attach(1)`